# How to deal with NIC frames in c++

Tags: networking, wifi, frames, ethernet, nic

I'm thinking about writing a  program as my junior project ...
the program should connect to different networks on the same system
i.e if  the PC  has 2 NIC each one with different type (e.g.Ethernet and WIFI  ) 
the program should read the frame from an NIC , changes the header so it matches the other NIC header's type , and then send it to the proper NIC ..

so can anyone direct me what to look for ,and what to read about in order to get this project done ??

the platform isn't that important to me , im ready to do it or linux or windows and the language is not a big deal also because im taking this project to learn as much as i can but as the title says , it would be  much better to have it in  c++

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) library would get you at least half of what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for your help sir , its true the library can do a lot of what im asking ,yet the documentation at the website says that the functions at this library are made and tested only on Ethernet NICs and are not guaranteed  to work over another topology

Comment: libpcap is used by [Firesheep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep) which was designed for WIFI, so while it is not guaranteed to work, it probably will.